# SendMailAsync Never Returns, Still Sends Mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, asp.net-core

I am sending mail via C#'s `SmtpClient.SendMailAsync`, but I am getting some very strange behavior.

When I make the call to `SendMailAsync` the email is sent - I receive it every time. However, my application never returns. It appears to hang on the `await` and I don't have any real insight into why it's not returning. If I switch to using `Send`, the mail sends immediately, and, of course, everything completes how I would expect.

Here is my source for actually sending the email.

```
public async Task SendEmailAsync(string toAddress, string subject, string message)
{
    using (var client = new SmtpClient(configuration["Email:Host"], Convert.ToInt32(configuration["Email:Port"])))
    using (var mailMessage = new MailMessage(configuration["Email:FromAddress"], toAddress, subject, message))
    {
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(configuration["Email:Username"], configuration["Email:Password"]);
        client.EnableSsl = true;

        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

        try
        {
            await client.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
        }
        catch (SmtpException)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Some other information that may or may not be helpful is that I'm sending these emails through AWS SES. No matter what address I send to, the same issue happens. My chain is Async all the way up the call stack. I'm running on OSX, ASP.NET Core 1.

Comment: Where is the outer `SendEmailAsync` method called?

Comment: @FedericoDipuma If you mean the caller method of `SendEmailAsync`, it's an asynchronous MVC controller action called `async Task<IActionResult> CreateAndAssign(...)`.

Comment: You mentioned you are running the app on OSX, can you isolate the issue and verify if it rises also in a Windows machine?

Comment: @FedericoDipuma Yes, let me get one of my other team members who are running Windows to try it out. I will let you know. As an aside - if I do not `await client.SendMailAsync` and instead just let the Task return, things seem to finish up properly. Don't know if that makes any difference. I will post an update as soon as I have one from my coworkers. Thank you.

Comment: If you are using `Kestrel` as server this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/103) could be related to your strange behavior. You could try to add `ConfigureAwait(false)` to your call to `client.SendMailAsync(mailMessage)` and see what happens.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma I just had a coworker test using Kestrel and running under Windows. The mail did send properly and the page reloaded, so it appears to be an issue specifically with something in OSX. Does your last comment still apply here (regarding Kestrel server and `ConfigureAwait`)? Thank you.

Comment: It could be that the Kestrel implementation in OSX/Linux still has the issue I described. ConfigureAwait(false) may be a workaround, let me know if it works.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma ConfigureAwait(false) did not appear to have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is a bug - perhaps with Kestrel on OSX per the discussion with Federico Dipuma in the comments. The workaround is to not send mail asynchronously.

Marking this as the answer unless more information can be uncovered.

Comment: Hi Sir, sorry for reviving this thread. But I'm also having the same problem. When I was running my program is localhost it works fine but when I hosted my website the mail is sending but SendMailAsync never returns. I'm just new with this kind of stuffs I hope you can help me Sir, thank you in advance. Here's my controller: http://pastie.org/10907763